# REDMINE on Debian 7 doesn't send mails over Exchange

Tags: exchange-server, redmine, debian-based

i'm running Redmine on Debian 7 and try to send mails via Mircosoft Exchange.

My configuration.yml looks like:

```
default:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
enable_starttls_auto: true
      address: <FIREWALLIP or SMTPIP>
      port: 25
      domain: <MYDOMAIN.local or mydomain.de>
      authentication: :login
      user_name: "username"
      password: "pwd"
```

I used both the Firewall and smtp ips and various combinations of domains and usernames to try it.

Sending the mail via telnet works with both ips.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

*edit* resolved:

works with this configuration:

```
    default:
    email_delivery:
    delivery_method: :smtp
    smtp_settings:
      address: <FIREWALLIP>
      port: 25
      domain: <mydomain.de>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

works with this configuration:

```
default:
email_delivery:
delivery_method: :smtp
smtp_settings:
  address: <FIREWALLIP>
  port: 25
  domain: <MYDOMAIN.local or mydomain.de>
  authentication: :login
  user_name: "username"
  password: "pwd"
```